# Can I listen to multiple domains in one ip on HTTP/3?

Tags: nginx, http

I'm using NGINX. I found that NGINX throws error when I set multiple domains for one HTTP/3 port.

```
    server {
        listen 443 http3 reuseport;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name FIRST_DOMAIN;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt-ecdsa/live/FIRST_DOMAIN/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt-ecdsa/live/FIRST_DOMAIN/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1.3;

        return 301 https://SECOND_DOMAIN$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 http3 reuseport;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name SECOND_DOMAIN default;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt-ecdsa/live/SECOND_DOMAIN/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt-ecdsa/live/SECOND_DOMAIN/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1.3;

        add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":443"; ma=86400';

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:10002/;
            proxy_set_header  Host              $http_host;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
```

```
nginx: [emerg] duplicate listen options for 0.0.0.0:443 in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:35
```

Can I listen to multiple domains in one ip on HTTP/3?

Comment: Did you solve? I’ve got the same issue

Answer (score -1):

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.hostname);
});

app.listen(40000);
```

I experimented about it with Node.js express. When I use HTTP/2, hostname printed. But when I use HTTP/3, `undefined` printed. This shows that HTTP/3 doesn't care about hostname. So, Listening to multiple domains in one HTTP/3 port is impossible. But you can open several ports for each HTTP/3 domains and add `Alt-Svc` header for advertise them to browser.

But according to my experience, `Alt-Svc` doesn't works stable depending on browser. So, you can't listen to multiple domains in one ip on HTTP/3 stably.

Comment: are you sure about this :  you can't listen to multiple domains in one ip on HTTP/3